# Pagespeed insights how to read score from API?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I would like to retrieve the global score through the API. In the runpagespeed response I only see 40+ individual scores.

Is there a way to retrieve the global score or should I just average all scores (hopefully they have same weight).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found it in:

```
json.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score
```

It has to be multiplied by 100.